# How to set a background image on GRUB?

Tags: grub2, images

Looking around on the internet I found a few screenshots of customized GRUB installations with a background image set, is that possible? How can I do that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The Ubuntu wiki has a [detailed guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Displays). First, you need to make sure the image is in the right format: a 256-color non-indexed RGB JPEG. GRUB checks a number of different places for background settings, and it varies by version; here is the first place checked for two versions:

#### 1.98

Open `/etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme`, look for the `WALLPAPER=` line, and set it to the correct path:

```
WALLPAPER=/path/to/your/bg.jpg
```

#### 1.99 and up

Open `/etc/default/grub` and add a new `GRUB_BACKGROUND` line:

```
GRUB_BACKGROUND=/path/to/your/bg.jpg
```

Update the grub configuration file:

```
update-grub
```

Comment: I hate to necromance, but for Debian in 2024, WALLPAPER is set in /usr/share/desktop-base/grub_background.sh.

Answer (score 12):

Just put any image under `/boot/grub/` and run

```
sudo update-grub
```

Answer (score 0):

There is this program grub-customizer: https://answers.launchpad.net/grub-customizer/+faq/1397.

It can also change the fonts color, the fonts, edit all the entries and more.
Your distribuition may have the package so you don' t have to build it.

If you want only to change the image you can do as suggested by user126697:

> Just put the image under /boot/grub/ and run
>
> ```
> sudo update-grub
> ```